# LightSwitch: Passing data from one screen to another

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, lightswitch-2012

Is it possible to pass one information from one screen to another?

This is my Main screen:

[image: main screen]

And I want to add one of the users into where "Leiter" is written.

[image: user screen]

Some idea how to manage it? Oh yeah, the data is coming from SharePoint...

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more? I don't see the word "Leiter" on either of those screens (though they are a little blurry so it could just be that). Can you explain what data you want to take from which screen, where you want it to appear on the 2nd screen, and HOW you want it to be passed (what is the user doing to make it happen)?

Answer (score 3):

In your List Detail, you need to create a Data Item to store the User Name. In the Properties for that Data Item, you then need to check "Is Parameter".

[image: is parameter check box]

When you call your second screen from the code in your `SearchUserInformationLists` screen, you pass the value of that Data Item to it.

`this.Application.ShowZeiterfassungsListDetail(this.MyUserName);`

The screen Parameters should be the first items in your list of Data Items on the left of the Screen Designer. You can pass more than one parameter and the order that you pass them in is the order in which they are listed in your Data Item list.

`this.Application.ShowZeiterfassungsListDetail(this.Param1, this.Param2, this.Param3);`