# Lightswitch - Passing Paramaters in the HTML Client

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

ive been trying for ages now to pass the value with little success, the image below is what I am aiming for:

[image: The Parameter I want to pass]

and this is the table structure/relationships
[image]

cheers for any help you can give me guys, this is beginning to be a real pain in the arse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on this I managed to solve my issue by doing the following

[LightSwitch: Passing data from one screen to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269515/lightswitch-passing-data-from-one-screen-to-another) -> for Desktop Client

For HTML Client

1. You MUST have a parameter on the screen from which you are passing the data, this is done by creating a data item, i.e. int in the below example, and in the post render code for this use the following code:

> ```
> myapp.ViewDeliveryNote.DeliveryIDPass_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
>
>     contentItem.screen.DeliveryIDPass = //created parameter
>     contentItem.screen.DeliveryNote.DeliveryID; //the unique ID from the screen
>
> };
> ```

2. On the screen you want to pass to, add a new data item as that datatype OR if you are using it as a search parameter, use this.
3. Find the parameter/data item you added on the left hand panel and click on the item, now in the properties window tick (is parameter)
4. If there was a previous link between the pages via a button, remove the on tap and re-add it... you will now see an additional box where the application is asking for the value to pass, select the one you want and that shoud work :)

hope this helps